# Installing wireless drivers in Ubuntu 20.04 running from an external hard drive, and without internet access

Tags: drivers, wireless, external-hdd

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external hard drive so that I can use Ubuntu on my MacBook Air without affecting the MacBook's internal SSD.

When I boot Ubuntu from the external drive, I cannot connect to the internet. I think this is because I need to install some drivers first. Unfortunately, my MacBook has no ethernet port, and so I will need to install these drivers offline, e.g. using a USB stick.

I'm unsure how I can find out which drivers I need to download, and I don't understand how I would then install them.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will identify your WiFi device and knowing that we know what it needs. Now, very likely your Macbook has a Broadcom WiFi chipset and those indeed require proprietary drivers. The easiest way to install them is by far with the help of a temporary internet connection. If you don't have an Ethernet port or USB Ethernet adapter the next best thing is USB tethering from your phone (any smartphone will do). Even if you have to use mobile data - WiFi bridging preferred - the total download is <50MB

Comment: Doing what you want to do is quite inconvenient due to some dependencies that you aren't aware of and only discover when trying to install and failing because it also needs such and such packet that you'll need to note down, go back to the computer with internet, search for and download them, rinse and repeat until you have everything you need (and then install all dependencies in order).

Comment: Also look here `https://help.ubuntu.com/search.html?cof=FORID%3A9&cx=003883529982892832976%3Ae2vwumte3fq&ie=UTF-8&q=macbook+air+wifi&sa=Search&siteurl=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Fcommunity%2FMacBook` see if you can find something

Comment: Try downloading and installing this deb `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3_amd64.deb`

Comment: @Inee This will be ineffective as a great many depencies are required: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GbZ689gYXw/